# Without using built-in functions, a function should reverse a string without changing the '$' position

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I need a Python function which gives reversed string with the following conditions.

1. `$` position should not change in the reversed string.
2. Should not use Python built-in functions.
3. Function should be an efficient one.

Example : `'pytho$n'`

Result : `'nohty$p'`

I have already tried with this code:

```
list = "$asdasdas"
list1 = []
position = ''
for index, i in enumerate(list):
    if i == '$':
        position = index
    elif i != '$':
        list1.append(i)
reverse = []
for index, j in enumerate( list1[::-1] ):
    if index == position:
        reverse.append( '$' )
    reverse.append(j)
print reverse
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It usually isn't helpful to overwrite the `list` builtin name. Choose something more descriptive like `characters` or `text`

Comment: Are you sure the result of your example is what you expect?

Comment: I edited the result.

Comment: Recognize the problem. You are being asked for something akin to 1 run of partition part of quicksort.

Comment: Nice brain-teaser, thanks for posting!
However, this question is not generally considered "worthy" of stackoverflow, don't be surprised if it gets deleted after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this without using any inbuilt functions. Hope it fulfils your criteria -

```
string = "zytho$n" 
def reverse(string):
    string_new = string[::-1]  
    i = 0
    position = 0
    position_new = 0
    for char in string:
        if char=="$":
            position = i
            break
        else:
            i = i + 1
    j = 0        
    for char in string_new:
        if char=="$":
            position_new = i
            break
        else:
            j = j + 1

    final_string = string_new[:position_new]+string_new[position_new+1:position+1]+"$"+string_new[position+1:]
    return(final_string)

string_new = reverse(string)    
print(string_new)
```

The output of this is-

```
nohty$x
```

To explain the code to you, first I used [::-1], which is just taking the last position of the string and moving forward so as to reverse the string. Then I found the position of the $ in both the new and the old string. I found the position in the form of an array, in case you have more than one $ present. However, I took for granted that you have just one $ present, and so took the [0] index of the array. Next I stitched back the string using four things - The part of the new string upto the $ sign, the part of the new string from after the dollar sign to the position of the $ sign in the old string, then the $ sign and after that the rest of the new string.

Comment: Hope it works?  Does this mean that you did not test it?

Comment: What I meant is hope this code fulfils all his "pre-conditions". I wrote it with TDD. Might I ask why it was down-voted? Since no reason is commented.

Comment: You do not show any results.  Just a code dump.  How do you know it works?  How have you shown to the reader that it works and why it works?  Why do you think a *hope* and some code is an answer?

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, is enumerate not an inbuilt function? I thought enumerate is the inbuilt function that's the reasonI posted this question here.

Comment: Okay I thought you meant any other in-built functions. Let me see.

Comment: @Santhosh re-wrote it without using enumerate.

Comment: this solution only works if there is only 1 $ character; not sure if that was a requirement though

Answer (score 0):

Recognise that it's a variation on the partitioning step of the [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) algorithm, using two pointers (array indices) thus:

```
data = list("foo$barbaz$$")

i, j = 0, len(data) - 1
while i < j:
    while i < j and data[i] == "$": i += 1
    while i < j and data[j] == "$": j -= 1
    data[i], data[j] = data[j], data[i]
    i, j = i + 1, j - 1

"".join(data)
'zab$raboof$$'
```

P.S. it's a travesty to write this in Python!

A Pythonic solution could look like this:

```
def merge(template, data):
    for c in template:
        yield c if c == "$" else next(data)

data = "foo$barbaz$$"
"".join(merge(data, reversed([c for c in data if c != "$"])))
'zab$raboof$$'
```